# ArchLinux multi home not responding on one interface

Tags: networking, cisco-asa, pfsense, timeout, multi-homed

I have a bunch of kit in a DC running through Cisco ASAs - this isn't really working out as it relies on us creating, paying and waiting for tickets concerning out network config.

I've been and installed a couple of R230s running pfSense, along with a couple of new switches.

The idea was to have the 2 (4) firewalls running side by side whilst we decide exactly how we want ruling to work on our pf boxes.

To test this out, on one of my servers I have the following config.

```
enp3s0f0:
IP: 10.66.82.16/24
GW: 10.66.82.1

enp4s0f0
IP: 10.44.50.100/24
GW: 10.44.50.250
```

Now, with either one of these disabled, things work as I expect - ie:

> **enp3s0f0 enabled, enp4s0f0 disabled:**
>
> > I can connect to the ASA VPN, and SSH (or otherwise connect to running apps)
>
> **enp3s0f0 disabled, enp4s0f0 enabled:**
>
> > I can connect to the pfSense VPN, and SSH (or otherwise connect to running apps)
>
> **enp3s0f0 enabled, enp4s0f0 enabled:**
>
> > If I connect to the pfSense VPN, I can connect via 10.44.50.100.
> >     Disconnecting from above, and connecting to the Cisco VPN, I can't connect to 10.66.82.16.

In all instances where I get no connection, it times out and is not rejected.

When both enabled, the routes (appear) to be correctly added;

```
default via 10.44.50.250 dev enp4s0f0  proto static
default via 10.66.82.1 dev enp3s0f0  proto static
10.44.50.0/24 dev enp4s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.44.50.100
10.66.82.0/24 dev enp3s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.66.82.16
```

I literally have no idea where to head from here, most stuff I've read about seems to identify ip_forwarding as the issue - I've tried this but don't think it relates to my setup on account of being two discrete network cards.

Any help will go a looooong way!

Thanks!
Dave.

Answer (score -2):

EXAMPLE WITH NETCTL

eth0 fixed / gateway: 10.18.100.1 fixed ip: 10.18.100.102

wlan0 dhcp / gateway: 10.18.110.1 fixed ip: 10.18.110.104 associated to wlan0's mac address

```
cat /etc/netctl/home-network

Description='Static Ethernet Connection'
Interface=net0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('10.18.100.102/24')
Gateway='10.18.100.1'
DNS=('8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8')

echo "123 rtac87u" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

cat /etc/netctl/home-wireless

Description='WPA-PSK'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
IP=dhcp
ESSID=ASUS5G1
#wpa_passphrase ASUS5G1 my-long-clear-text-psk
Key=\"string-generated-by-wpa_passphrase
ExecUpPost="ip route add default via 10.18.110.1 dev wlan0 table rtac87u; ip rule add from 10.18.110.104 table rtac87u"

netctl reenable home-network

netctl reenable home-wireless

netctl restart home-network

netctl restart home-wireless
```